# Cannot delete a directory in Windows - not even as Administrator

Tags: windows, command-line

I have a directory tree which I want to delete, located in my home directory.

I tried both from the GUI and from the command prompt, both as user and as Administrator:

```
rmdir /s /q .\dirName
```

I get this error message:

```
.\dirName - The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
```

I do not care what other processes are accessing that directory, even because the most likely one is VSCode which I already closed.

All I want is to delete that directory tree, and my wish has priority over any other (closed) process that pretends to be using it. Even if these other processes should crash. Even if these other processes's crash should cause Windows to crash.

Anything like `rm -r` from Linux?

OS version: Microsoft Windows 10 (Version 10.0.19044.2251)

Comment: Use Unlocker 1.9.2 (Major Geeks) to delete the files in the folder, and then delete the folder. Works here.

Comment: I'm using LockHunter for the same

Comment: Microsoft Powertoys also contains [File Locksmith](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/file-locksmith) that you can use to help diagnose the issue.

Comment: Thank you all for pointing me to these tools. I tried LockHunter, and it worked. @EugeneSh., if you write it as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Last but not least, you can use SystemInternals Process Explorer to find and close handles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a lot of options. you can download proccess explorer from microsoft sysinternals suite from here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer
then search for the directory to find out which process is using it. kill the process and delete the directory.

other options are: iobit unlocker, unlocker, magic unlocker, lockhunter, file locksmith, delinvfile, wise force deleter... and the list goes on and on.